# KIVY: How can I get the scroll direction in kivy?

Tags: python, scroll, kivy

I found this piece of code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class Test(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Test, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_touch_down=self.window_on_touch_down)

    def window_on_touch_down(self, *args):
        print(args)
        # scrolling the wheel down will give <MouseMotionEvent button="scrollup"

        if '<MouseMotionEvent button="scrollup"' in args:
            print('hello')


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

and while it prints the scrollup motion I can't use it... args has the string in it but the if doesn't work and "hello" isn't printed... anybody know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see in the prints are python objects not strings.
So you can't just check for a string.

A better way to get what you want is to check *what* button produces the `MouseMotionEvent`

```py
    def window_on_touch_down(self, window, mouse_event):
        # scrolling the wheel down will give <MouseMotionEvent button="scrollup"
        if mouse_event.button == "scrollup":
            print('hello')
```